# Documents about ZUC

Tags: reference-request, stream-cipher

ZUC is a function that converts a string to another string. However, unlike a Hash function, ZUC converts a certain-length string to a any-length string.

Can someone point me to its documentation or the specification?

Comment: Please keep in mind that ***Crypto.SE is not a replacement for your favorite search engine***. (It is hard to imagine that the search engine you use was not able to point you to the related Wikipedia article – [***“ZUC stream cipher”***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zuc_stream_cipher) – which lists the specs in its “References” section.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest version (1.6) can be found on http://www.gsma.com or http://dacas.iie.cas.cn/. Direct links:

- [Specification of the 3GPP Confidentiality and Integrity Algorithms 128-EEA3 & 128-EIA3. Document 2: ZUC Specification](http://www.gsma.com/aboutus/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/eea3eia3zucv16.pdf) (pdf) on gsma.com
- [ZUC算法文档v1.6](http://dacas.iie.cas.cn/zucsf/sfjsxwd/201405/P020140504837433390403.zip) (zip) on dacas.iie.cas.cn (contains a bit more information such as more test vectors)

Comment: Thanks @Artjom. Lots of noise while searching until this showed up. It is too bad they don't provide test vectors.